# Authorize.net AVS error page handling

Tags: error-handling, authorize.net, avs

I am simulating an AVS error and the response displayed -

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant.
An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. 
The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

The transaction has been declined because of an AVS mismatch. 
The address provided does not match billing address of cardholder.
```

There is nothing else on the screen, the url is pointing to https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll

I hate to give this option to the client without some type of instruction like a back button. Other simulated errors usually stay on the form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when Authorize.Net is trying to contact your website's relay response page and it does not respond successfully withing a specified period of time. [Authorize.Net offers more detail on their website](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536).